# Using ArcPy cursor to concatenate row values?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor, attributeerror

I am ArcGIS 10 user and I want to create ArcPy script for simple concatenate row values like this tool [Concatenate Row Value](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=52dfcef46fdb4c76bfbc08dc01570f3c) that works with ArcGIS 10.

I have three fields in my shapefile `id,field1,field2`.

Here the image from my shapefile `.dbf` after sort by id.

[image: image1]

If you see the image you can see the id not have unique values.

I want to create the layer with unique id values but I don't want to loose some values from field2 (is text). For field2 I need to use for next conditions.

In Excel if I use some condition like this:

```
=IF(AND(A3=A2;C3=C2);D2;IF(AND(A3=A2;C3<>C2);D2;IF(AND(A3=A2;C3<>C2);D2&","&C3;C3)))
```

Then I take new field to like this:

[image: new field]

That works in Excel, I want to do with Python or ArcPy or some tool from ArcGIS.

In QGIS, it is easy for me to do with this plugin that does `dissolve with stats`.

I try to follow this code:

```
updateFields = ["id", "field2", "field3"]

with arcpy.UpdateCursor("featurelayer", updateFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0]+1 == row[0] and row[2]+1==row[2]:
            row[3] = row[2]
        elif row[0]+1 == row[0] and row[2]+1!=row[2]:
            row[3] = row[2]
        elif row[0]+1 == row[0] and row[2]+1!=row[2]:
            row[3] = row[2]+','+row[2]+1
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

That looks correct but any time to try to run it I take this error:

```
 Cursor AttributeError: __exit__
```

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: use the calculate filed (data mangement) in arcpy to do this. here is the help docs http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm

Comment: @Joe i have read this many times but that doc not help for my question,how to this with  calculate filed ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more clear? What are the conditions of concatenating your fields? Do you simply want all three together (see below)? Or to have if statements like your provided code? If so please type out these conditions or what you have tried, the code provided in incoherent imo.

Comment: None of your `if` conditions will **ever** be true. This has the same problem as the previous post, in that you are trying to use DA cursor syntax with an old-style cursor.

Comment: In the future, please do not delete and repost a question.

Comment: @Vince tell me some solution,how to convert that code to work ?

Comment: It's not possible for that code to work. You need to start over with an appropriate flow of control template for regular cursors (as in the documentation), then start working on a way to initialize to `None` and retain the previous row contents before invoking `next`. Then you'll have a chance  at making code which can be tested. As @Midavalo wrote, `There is no way for us to explain how to fix your code unless you explain what you think it should be doing.`

Comment: @Vince i have update my ask

Comment: I've already told you *exactly* how to eliminate the error.

Comment: Defining your numeric as a Integer is always helpful when dealing with manipulation of numeric values..also Perl is a tremendous way to prepare raw data prior to database loading

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/118324)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to concatenate three fields into a new field. You can use the field calculator say you create a new field called "conc" for your concatenated strings.

eg. field1=dog field 2=cat, field3=moose

Right click on the "conc" field and go to field calculator, change to python:

Then write:

```
!field1! + !field2! + !field3!
```

To concatenate all three fields into your new conc field. Giving you:

```
dogcatmoose
```

See the [ESRI blog for more concatenation](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/08/30/concatenate/).

**Based on the new edits**:

There's a tool already called ["Concatenate Row Values"](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/05/concatenaterowvalues/) that looks to do exactly what you want - which takes identical row values (like your id field) and concatenates the values in a given row into a new one.

Comment: that i need but i want to do this only in features where have some value in my `field1` (look the picture in my post)

Comment: @Mar myself and the other commenters do not understand what your conditions are - I would edit your post to make that clearer and we can try and help.

Comment: i have update my ask

Comment: @Mar based on your edit, there is already a tool that does this:https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/05/concatenaterowvalues/

Comment: but that tool not work on ArcGIS 10.0,see the comments

Comment: @Mar I'm not seeing that. Did you try using it? Did you get an error?

Comment: the link for argis 10.0 is dead and if I try t use that tool then the toobox in argis 10 is empty

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to iterate with a cursor and then make use of a dictionary to store past values found.

```
#empty dictionary to hold past values
di = {}

#cursor to iterate rows
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("featurelayer", ["id", "field2", "final_field"]) as curs:
    for Id, val, finalVal in curs:
        #update dictionary
        try: di [Id] += [val]
        except: di [Id] = [val]

        #get all values and create string
        vals = di [Id]
        valStr = ",".join (map (str, vals))

        #update row
        row = (Id, val, valStr)
        curs.updateRow (row)
```

For 10.0 and before:

```
#empty dictionary to hold past values
di = {}

#cursor to iterate rows
curs = arcpy.UpdateCursor ("featurelayer")
for row in curs:
    #update dictionary
    Id = row.getValue ("id")
    val = row.getValue ("field2")
    try: di [Id] += [val]
    except: di [Id] = [val]

    #get all values and create string
    vals = di [Id]
    valStr = ",".join (map (str, vals))

    #update row
    row.setValue ("final_field", valStr)
    curs.updateRow (row)

del curs
```

Comment: can I use .da in ArcGIS 10.0 ?

Comment: @Mar Negative. See edit.

Comment: your code dont work,you are sure ?